# Discrete Math Strings

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

Question: 7. A string that is obtained by rearranging the letters of the word
BOOGER is called awesome, if the string does not contain the substring OO. Thus, GEOROB is awesome, whereas GREOOB is not awesome. What is the number of awesome strings?

Answer: (6 * 5C2 * 3 * 2 * 1)

Attempt: What I did was calculate the number of ways the string contains the substring OO, which I found to be 5!, I treated OO as one letter. Then I subtracted it from the total number of possible substrings 6!.I'm not sure where I went wrong, would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you saying you obtained $600$ and the book's answer is $360$?

Comment: Yes. The answer is 360, but I'm getting 600.

Comment: I don't think either you or the book is right. I think the answer is $240$. If I understand the problem correctly, which is hardly a foregone conclusion. Maybe I can ask a clarifying question: What do you think the answer would be if I asked how many awesome permutations there are of BOO? Of BOOR?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked again and I confused it with another answer. It is 240. To answer your question, would that be 2!.

Comment: No, it isn't $2$. Try listing out the awesome permutations of BOO and of BOOR. There are not that many. In fact, while you're at it, list *all* the permutations of BOO and of BOOR. That may help you see why your approach, even though it is sound in principle, isn't yielding the right answer. ¶ By the way, if you suddenly get it, please resist the urge to delete the question. It can be useful for future readers.

Comment: Can't you have RBOO and BOOR?

Comment: Aren't those both non-awesome? I thought the awesome ones were the ones without consecutive O's. I'll post an answer; you can check to see if it answers the question the way you want.

Comment: Oh sorry. I was thinking you were asking a different type of question. I wrote it out so ROBO, OROB, OBOR, BORO,

Comment: You're missing ORBO and OBRO, so a total of $6$. My answer shows how to get this as either $4!/2-3! = 12-6 = 6$ (which is your approach, only suitably fixed) or $3 \times 2 = 6$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Incidentally, a minor language issue that may confuse some readers: We would typically say "I subtracted it *from* the total number..." rather than "I subtracted it by the total number..."

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $240$, which (as the comments indicate) is actually the result the OP's book provides. Here are two ways to obtain that answer:

First, to apply the method the OP uses, we need only fix one minor error—there are not $6! = 720$ different permutations of BOOGER, but only $6!/2 = 360$. The reason is that the two O's are not distinguishable. If we permute BO$_1\!$O$_2\!$GER, there are $720$ different sequences, but in ordinary text, there is no difference between BO$_1\!$O$_2\!$GER and BO$_2\!$O$_1\!$GER, and in general, each permutation of BO$_1\!$O$_2\!$GER has an indistinguishable "twin". Therefore, the correct answer is $6!/2 - 5! = 360-120 = 240$.

A second approach is to first decide where to put the two O's. There are ten possibilities: OXOXXX, OXXOXX, OXXXOX, OXXXXO, XOXOXX, XOXXOX, XOXXXO, XXOXOX, XXOXXO, and XXXOXO. The remaining four spots (marked by X's above) can be replaced by the four remaining letters B, G, E, and R in $4! = 24$ different ways. So the number of awesome permutations is $10 \times 24 = 240$.

Answer (score 0):

Permute $BGER$ in $4!$ ways and punch holes at two of the five uparrows $\uparrow B \uparrow G \uparrow E \uparrow R \uparrow$  for the two $O's$ to get the corrected answer of $4!\binom 52 =240$